# Symbolic link source item can't be found

Tags: macos, bash, shell, alias, symlink

I'm trying to make an alias of a directory in a set of directories

```
for D in $(find * -maxdepth 0 -type d) ; do
    ln -s location/to/directory/ $D/Test2 ;
done
```

It looks like the link is made correctly (I can see it in my finder window), but when I double click it, I get the error `The operation can't be completed because the original item for "Test2" can't be found.`

Why doesn't this work? Is there a way from a bash script to make a "normal" mac alias? I have opened up the permissions, as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/131615), without any luck.

Answer (score 9):

Use the absolute source path while creating the link. That worked for me having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a symbolic link called `Test2` in each directory in the current directory, and each created link should point to `location/to/directory`.

```
for dir in */; do
    ln -s 'location/to/directory' "$dir/Test2"
done
```

The slash after `*` ensures that we will only match directories in the current directory, or links to directories in the current directory.

If you're only interested in real directories an not symbolically linked directories, you may use

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    -exec ln -s 'location/to/directory' {}/Test2 ';'
```

Note that the link destination is relative to the location of the link, so if a directory does not contain `location/to/directory`, the link will be "dead".

You may solve this be specifying an absolute path for the links.

Answer (score -1):

What are you attempting to do?

Think of a *link* as a `cp` command. Maybe that will help:

```
# Copies the 'svnadmin' command from /opt/svn/bin to /usr/local/bin
$ cp /opt/svn/bin/svnadmin /usr/local/bin

# Links the 'svnadmin' command from /opt/svn/bin to /usr/local/bin
$ ln -s /opt/svn/bin/svnadmin /usr/local/bin
```

Note that the `ln` and `cp` command have the same order of files.

In your command, you're linking whatever `location/to/directory/` to `$D/test2` over and over again.

Also, `-maxdepth 0` won't be in the first level of the directory.

I use `ln` when I install new software, and the binary commands are in some other directory. Instead of building on `$PATH` to include all of these extra directories, I symbolically link them to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ cd /usr/share/apache-ant/bin
$ for file in *
> do
>     [[ -f $file ]] || continue
>     ln -s $PWD/$file /usr/local/bin/$file
> done
```

Note that the link simply copies the entire reference for the first file to the link. I want to make sure that this link works everywhere, so I prefix that `$PWD` in front of it. This way, my links look like this:

```
$ ls -l ant
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  29 Sep  3  2014 ant -> /usr/share/apache-ant/bin/ant
```

Comment: If the symlink B point to A, Is asking why cannot open the resource A when do a double click with finder on B.

Comment: @jjalonso Except the Mac's Finder **does** open the symlink when double clicked when the link can be found. I do this with `$HOME/Documents` making it a symbolic link to `$HOME/Dropbox/Documents`. Double clicking on `$HOME/Documents` in the Finder works as expected. Same with the Dock or Pathfinder. All programs I use have no problems with the symbolic link. As far as the Mac is concerned, the `$HOME/Documents` directory is there. If the OP is having problems with the symlink, the symlink is not being made correctly. That's why I suggested putting the full path in the symlink.

Comment: David, your comment about using the full path in the symlink did the trick for me. Thanks!